# Partial html Navigation using ES6

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

Hi I'm creating a basic ES6 application with page navigation without frameworks. I have experiences that angular 2 is having `@component` with `templateUrl:"index.html"` to navigate to another page.

upto now I have create my page to navigate on click to another page using,

`window.location.href = '';`

which this will load a whole html page with html tags and all. I want to use partial HTML files like angular 2 usage, without html tags for all pages.

the question is how can I do that, if I'm using **ES6 web components** How can I use separate files for navigation process.

Comment: You will have to build your own framework for loading templates via ajax (and also an entire routing library if you want dynamic routing). Angular does *a lot* of things in the back and you can't just use those Angular-specific concepts in vanilla JS.

Comment: You should use Ajax

Comment: Create a template file with some syntax. I suggest using ${} syntax for variables so you can later use ES6 template literals to populate it. Then you ajax that file into your core. Register an onhashchange event on the browser and start using hyperlinks like : http://myhost/mypage#myTemplate. Every time one of those links gets used, hashchange triggers and you can extract myTemplate name from the hash. Render the template file with that name into the DOM in the right location. That's more or less basic templating and routing.

Comment: The problem is, there's no such thing as *ES6 web components*. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components are still experimental, so it's unclear what the subject is about.

Comment: its all about navigation process for my application. simply a partial html.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, EJS is not providing that kind of facility. You can't change part of EJS using it.

What you can do is use ajax for the same. You can create ajax file and request to node server and change content accordingly.